# Tweening Object3D towards camera in Three.js - this works, need to set new screen position

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have some code that tweens an object towards the camera and fits to half the screen

```
    var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180; 
    var ratio = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 );
    var screen = ratio * (window.innerWidth * 0.6 / window.innerHeight * 0.6) ; 
    var size = getCompoundBoundingBox( object ).max.y;
    var width = getCompoundBoundingBox( object ).max.x;
    var dist = (size/screen) * (object.scale.x * 2); 

    //get final position in front of camera
    var pLocal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -dist );

    //apply the direction the camera is facing
    var target = pLocal.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );

    //tween the object towards the camera
    var tweenMove = new TWEEN.Tween(object.position).to(target, 1500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut);
```

The next thing I need to do is able able to move it either to the left or up, for other UI on the screen and the responsive element.

i.e. to move it to the left 3rd, or top third. It also needs to still be square onto the camera.

I've tried changing the pLocal value to something like (1, 0, - dist) but this just rotates the object when it tweens up.

Any ideas how I can add that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a new look position to left of camera